# Unable to fetch page using POST

Tags: php, post

I'm on a government site: http://bit.ly/10N0Ld8 and when I click on the Select ( as shown in the image with a blue rectangle) it fetches some data. This "fetch" I want to do from my PHP program. I've grabbed the POST data using Firebug. But it is failing to get the same data. I've tried removing arguments etc but nothing is working. The site is returning error of "Sorry this site has encountered a serious problem, please try reloading the page or contact webmaster."

Any idea - how I can fetch this value programmatically?

This is the source code I've used: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7aEugGV1GwTdHRhXzZnXzNrNVE/edit?usp=sharing . The Curl code is working correctly as I've tested another POST request.

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code here rather than linking to it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7aEugGV1GwTdHRhXzZnXzNrNVE/edit

Comment: With ASP, you need to make a request to the page first, get the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` and then make a `POST` request with your new values. `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` are session specific

Comment: I don't know ASP nor have any experience on it. Is there any way to do it in PHP/Perl etc?

Answer (score 0):

__VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION are unique every time you load the page so you need to first retrieve the page, then make a request to the Select link with POST and including the fetched values of viewstate and eventvalidation (with DOM preferably).

```
$viewstate = $xpath->query(...);
```